# Make squares in a square grid always square

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle, where I'm trying to make the grid of colored squares always square, regardless of the size of the screen:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
}

#boardgrid{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

#boardgrid>div{
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
}

#boardgrid>div>div{
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 8;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 8 / 8;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 8 / 2;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 9 / 2 / 10 / 8;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.black{
  background-color: black;
}

.lightgreen{
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div id="boardgrid">
      <div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
```

The height and location of the squares are correct, but I need the width of the squares to always be equal to their height. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: you are using percentage in width and height, so it adjust according to screen size, so if you view this in a smaller screen you will see squares, either use px, or assign row height to square width

Comment: Setting width and heigth in pixels means the grid loses its shape if the screen is resized too small. I want the grid to keep the same square shape.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with matching height to percentage width is to use `padding-top` instead of `height` because `padding-top` is based on width instead of height. You can use the code as below. If you need any content within the divs. You can add `position: relative` in the colored divs and `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;` in the children divs to adjust the contents within the boxes.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 95vh;
  width: 95vw;
}

#boardgrid{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

#boardgrid>div{
  float: left;
  width:100%;
}

#boardgrid>div>div{
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 8;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 8 / 8;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 8 / 2;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 9 / 2 / 10 / 8;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.black{
  background-color: black;
}

.lightgreen{
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <div id="boardgrid">
      <div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="black"></div>
        <div class="lightgreen"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the grid goes completely out of the window with this solution.